# Changing Style of Add to Cart Button in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using storefront theme in woocommerce with custom home page and for some reason, the add  to cart button appears differently on home page and archive pages (search results, categories etc.). I am guessing its because I use custom home page. While on home page it appears normally as button, on shop page or categories, it appears as text link along with small basket icon. I have tried everything to fix this, even used custom add to cart button plugins but nothing worked so far.

Could somebody be kind enough to tell me how to make add to cart appear as button in categories and search page? I will really appreciate it. Below are screenshot for your reference.

Home Page - https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hH1g.jpg
Product Category Page - https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHJn9.jpg (need to fix this one)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a magic answer here. There are thousands of themes and plugins that can all influence your add to cart style. Follow the *rough* outline below to apply the style.

Use the inspect console. Right click and inspect the button and take note of the styles being applied to the button you want.

In another tab open the page with the buttons you want changed inspect the buttons and build a rule that adequately targets the buttons. Then apply the styles making changes as needed.

Once satisfied copy the entire style rule and add it to your themes styles.css or use a plugin that allows you to add css (https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried looking into the css and think the below code is changing the style of add to cart button. Could you be kind enough to check.

.added_to_cart,
.button,
button:not(.pswp__button),
input[type=button],
input[type=reset],
input[type=submit],
.woocommerce-active .site-header .site-header-cart a.cart-contents {
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); }

Comment: @MayankG No I cannot. I do not have your setup installed to validate your styles. I simply provided a method on how you can, yourself, apply the styles you want.

Comment: thanks I managed to do that with your trick.